# Find substring in a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, substring

I have a list like so and I want to be able to search within this list for a substring coming from another string.  Example:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string srch = "There";
list.Add("1234 - Hello");
list.Add("4234 - There");
list.Add("2342 - World");
```

I want to search for `"There"` within my list and return `"4234 - There"`.  I've tried:

```
var mySearch = list.FindAll(S => s.substring(srch));
foreach(var temp in mySearch)
{
    string result = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With Linq, just retrieving the first result:

```
string result = list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(srch));
```

To do this w/o Linq (e.g. for earlier .NET version such as .NET 2.0) you can use `List<T>`'s `FindAll` method, which in this case would return all items in the list that contain the search term:

```
var resultList = list.FindAll(delegate(string s) { return s.Contains(srch); });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer, I'm getting a compile error:  FirstOrDefault and not extension method.  Do I need to add sometype of list library?

Comment: How to add Linq?  Sorry for newby question.

Comment: you need to add a `using System.Linq` to your file - I assume you are using .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: My project was set to 2.0, I changed to 4.0 but now its a big mess of compile errors.  Was able to add System.Linq however.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Of course you can also use the short form (`s => s.Contains(srch)`) for `FindAll`.

Comment: Whats about 'IgnoreCase' ?

Answer (score 13):

To return all th entries:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = list.Where(s => s.Contains(search));
```

Only the first one:

```
string result = list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(search));
```

Comment: This 'where' doesnt work, returns empty List.  The selected answer do the job.

Comment: @Jhollman: nope, it works fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/bjuZ5p Check your code, you might ran into a casing issue. Feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written causes the compile error

> The best overloaded method match for 'string.Substring(int)' has some invalid arguments

Substring is used to get part of string using character position and/or length of the resultant string.

for example 
`srch.Substring(1, 3)` returns the string "her"

As other have mentioned you should use `Contains` which tells you if one string occurs within another. If you wanted to know the actual position you'd use `IndexOf`

Answer (score 1):

same problem i had to do.

You need this:

```
myList.Where(listStrinEntry => myString.IndexOf(listStringEntry) != -1)
```

Where:

`myList` is `List<String>` has the values
that `myString` has to contain at any position

**So de facto you search if myString contains any of the entries from the list.**
Hope this is what you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

i like to use indexOf or contains

```
someString.IndexOf("this");
someString.Contains("this");
```

Answer (score 0):

And for `CaseSensitive` use:

```
YourObj yourobj = list.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.SomeString.ToLower().Contains("some substring"));
```

OR

```
YourObj yourobj = list.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.SomeString.ToUpper().Contains("some substring"));
```