# determine whether the elements of the list of strings, which contains substring

Tags: c#, string, list, substring

I have a list of `String`s.

How can I check if the list of `String`s contains a string with the prefix `2#`?

I saw this:
[Find substring in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488587/find-substring-in-a-list-of-strings)

I tried the following:

```
if ((startId == item.ID.ToString())
       && (item.NextButtons.Contains(s => s.Contains("2#")))) ;
   {
     OK = false;
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
yourList.Any(s => s.Contains("2#"))
```

Use the LINQ `Any` method to determine if any element of a collections satisfies the condition.

The condition is a lambda method that takes each `string` element of your list as an input parameter and checks if it `Contains` the string `"2#"`. It does this until the first one is found and then returns either `true` or `false`.

If you wanted to return the actual string, you would use the `FirstOrDefault` method instead of `Any`. It would then return either the string or `null`, if none are found.

edit: if the `2#` has to be at the start of the string, see @Some1.Kill.The.DJ's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want  `2#` in front of them..

So,it should be

```
yourList.Any(s => s.StartsWith("2#"));
                    -----------
```

Comment: @Rotem you were right..just did a minor correction to ur anwer ;)