# How to check if List contains part of a value?

Tags: c#, list

I was wondering if it possible to check if a List contains part of a value. If it finds the value then return the value.

E.g. If the List had values 12345, 14567 and 14785, I want to search if the List contains '123', 
Is this possible?

If it is can all values that contain '123' be returned?

This is how I add values to the List:

```
recordFailedPO.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dataGWHeight.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value));
```

This is how I'm checking for a part of a value:

```
            if (recordFailedPO.Contains(currentPO))
            {
               // Code Here
            }
```

Where currentPO is the user input.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not by handling them as integers. Store them as, or convert them to strings and use `.Where(s => s.Contains(currenyPO))`. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488587/find-substring-in-a-list-of-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to convert to string before

```
int res = recordFailedPO.Find(x=>x.ToString().Contains(currentPO));
```

All values can be returned by `FindAll` .

```
 List<int> res = recordPO.FindAll(x=>x.ToString().Contains(currentPO)):
```

Answer (score 2):

In that case you could use string `Contains` method

```
var containsNumber = recordFailedPO.Where(x => x.ToString().Contains("123"));
```